# Unable to set X-Frame Options on apache 2.4.18 server running on Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: configuration, webserver, ubuntu-16.04, apache2.4, x-frame-options

I am trying to set the X-Frame-Options to Deny on our webpage with the following: Header set X-Frame-Options DENY

[image: apache2.conf file]

All the documentation i can find says this is where it should be (inside the apache2.conf file).

But i keep getting this output after restarting the server

[image: Output after restart]

I have tried:

"Header set X-Frame-Options DENY"

"Header Set X-Frame-Options DENY"

"header set X-Frame-Options Deny

"HEADER set X-Frame-Options DENY"

"HEADER Set X-Frame-Options DENY"

and many more along the above pattern.

Again from all the documentation this should be as simple as adding one line of code or am I missing something blindingly obvious?

I have also tried creating a httpd.conf file and linking this with an include in the apache2.conf.

I managed to add the FileETag None with no problems however only really added this as a test to make sure i was adding the code to the right place.

Any suggestions why this would be happening?

I am new to web-server configuration so please be gentle in your replies :)

Comment: I have also tried setting the X-Frame-Options under <directory/> and even outside any of the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. So it turns out barely anywhere mentions to run sudo a2enmod headers first to enable to headers module.

Also it turns out this is added in the security.conf file not the apache2.conf file

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the below line in httpd.conf
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so in httpd.conf
Add below line
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
not inside the the  tag